# Why does this TensorFlow example not have a summation before the activation function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm trying to understand a TensorFlow code snippet. What I've been taught is that we sum all the incoming inputs and then pass them to an activation function. Shown in the picture below is a single neuron. Notice that we compute a weighted sum of the inputs and THEN compute the activation.

[image: picture]

In most examples of the multi-layer perceptron, they don't include the summation step. I find this very confusing.

Here is an example of one of those snippets:

```
weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1])),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_classes]))
}
biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}


# Create model
def multilayer_perceptron(x):
    # Hidden fully connected layer with 256 neurons
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1']))
    # Hidden fully connected layer with 256 neurons
    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2']))
    # Output fully connected layer with a neuron for each class
    out_layer = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['out']) + biases['out'])
    return out_layer
```

In each layer, we first multiply the inputs with a `weights`. Afterwards, we add the `bias` term. Then we pass those to the `tf.nn.relu`. Where does the summation happen? It looks like we've skipped this!

Any help would be really great!

Comment: It's done by [`softmax`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax) as far as I understand, it's the equivalent of `softmax = tf.exp(logits) / tf.reduce_sum(tf.exp(logits), axis)`

Comment: Okay -- the softmax layer does it. But the other nodes don't do it?

Comment: No I don't think so as this wouldn't make sense, if you sum or perform any kind of aggregation, they stop becoming a layer so you can't feed them to another layer

Comment: It does remain a layer. Each individual neuron in a layer takes input and each neuron has to produce a single scalar value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tf.matmul operator performs a matrix multiplication, which means that each element in the resulting matrix is a sum of products (which corresponds exactly to what you describe).

Take a simple example with a row-vector and a column-vector, as would be the case if you had exactly one neuron and an input vector (as per the graphic you shared above);

x = [2,3,1]
y = [3,
     1,
     2]

Then the result would be:

tf.matmul(x, y) = 2*3 + 3*1 +1*2 = 11

There you can see the weighted sum.

p.s: tf.multiply performs element-wise multiplication, which is not what we want here.

Answer (score 2):

The last layer of your model `out_layer` outputs probabilities of each class `Prob(y=yi|X)` and has shape `[batch_size, n_classes]`. To calculate these probabilities the [softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function)
function is applied. For each single input data point `x` that your model receives it outputs a vector of probabilities `y` of size number of classes. You then pick the one that has highest probability by applying `argmax` on the output vector `class=argmax(P(y|x))` which can be written in tensorflow as `y_pred = tf.argmax(out_layer, 1)`.

Consider network with a single layer. You have input matrix `X` of shape `[n_samples, x_dimension]` and you multiply it by some matrix `W` that has shape `[x_dimension, model_output]`. The summation that you're talking about is dot product between the row of matrix `X` and column of matrix `W`. The output will then have shape `[n_samples, model_output]`. On this output you apply activation function (if it is the final layer you probably want softmax). Perhaps the picture that you've shown is a bit misleading.

Mathematically, the layer without bias can be described as [image] and suppose that the first row of matrix [image] (the first row is a single input data point) is

[image]

and first column of `W` is

[image]

The result of this dot product is given by

[image]

which is your summation. You repeat this for each column in matrix `W` and the result is vector of size `model_output` (which correspond to the number of columns in `W`). To this vector you add bias (if needed) and then apply activation.

Comment: I updated the question to use the relu activation function at the end of the network. I don't think it should matter what the activation function is.